# Delete Associated Media Upon Page / Post Deletion

Tags: plugins, media-library, customization

I found [this code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109793/delete-associated-media-upon-page-deletion/188421).

But not work for me. Where to insert the code? 
I try

wp-content/theme/mytheme/functions.php - not work.

wp-includes/post.php - not work.

wp-includes/functions.php - not work.

And I make plugin (but this the first), not work. [Plugin download](http://www.filedropper.com/delete).

My Wordpress version is 4.2.2.

Big Thanks, and sorry I'm rookie!

Comment: which solution you are trying to use (out of the two, given in so question)? I'd suggest not to edit the WordPress core files directly, `wp-includes/post.php`, `wp-includes/functions.php`, never edit those files

Comment: I trying insert the code in above php - not work. After I trying make plugin (link above) - not work.

Okey, I don't edit core files!
(My English maybe not good sorry)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete Associated Media Upon Page Deletion](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109793/delete-associated-media-upon-page-deletion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for clarity: borrowing from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/109804/1685), add the following to your theme's `functions.php`:

```
function wpse_188427_delete_post_media( $post_id ) {
    $attachments = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_status'    => 'any',
            'post_parent'    => $post_id,
        )
    );
    
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        wp_delete_attachment( $attachment->ID );
    }
}

add_action( 'before_delete_post', 'wpse_188427_delete_post_media' );

// Uncomment the following line if you also want to delete media when the post is trashed
// add_action( 'wp_trash_post', 'wpse_188427_delete_post_media' );
```